# REVISTED$^1$: Circumstantial Proof: $P\implies Q \overset{?}{\implies} Q\implies P$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

To prove that if a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n} ( F )$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizable is enough to show that the opposite holds? That is, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ has distinct eigenvalues?

Please don't answer the actual question. I want to do it myself. I just want to know if it suffice to show the opposite *in this particular case.*

[image]

[image]

### EDIT$^1$:

If $A$ is similar to a diagonlizable matrix, then $A$ is diagonalizable, right?

Comment: Note that *in this particular case* the statement $P\Rightarrow Q$ is in fact wrong. There are diagonal(izable) matrices with non-distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: Just curious, in this context, what might ${\cal{V}}_{e_i}$ stand for?

Comment: I'm reading Larry Smith's *Linear Algebra* (third edition). He uses it. I think I'll find out what it means eventually, but maybe someone knows.

Comment: The image is of page 119 from James M. Ortega's *Matrix Theory*.

Comment: Page 118 is sort of necessary to see the result a bit clearer. I can put that one up if you ask me to.

Comment: With regard to EDIT$^1$: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It would only prove the *converse*.

$$\underbrace{P \implies Q}_{\text {implication}} \quad\not\equiv \underbrace{Q \implies P}_{\text{converse of implication}}$$

If you need to prove $P \implies Q$, you **can** prove its equivalent:

$$\underbrace{\lnot Q \implies \lnot P}_{\text{contrapositive of implication}}$$

Comment: OK, I'll try that last step of yours you mentioned, but wait, do you know how to add sideways braces on the left or right or a matrix in tex?

Comment: The converse is actually harder... I think...

Comment: Try \lbrace, or \rbrace, before the matrix.

Comment: What about at a particular portion of the matrix, say, 1/3 of the way up?

Comment: So distinct here means linearly independent?

Comment: I don't know that, off hand. Sorry! Try experimenting a little bit?  ;-)  I learn mathjax as I go along...and a lot of trial and error!

Comment: 10 minutes, calm down...

Comment: I mean the column vectors of the diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: @amWhy: You do such a great job with these! =1

Answer (score 2):

To help on this point of logic, let me try something I suggest to my students. You take the sentence

> If it's raining, then the ground is wet.

as a reasonable one. And the *contrapositive*

> If the ground is dry, then it is not raining.

seems equivalent and totally reasonable, as well. (So these are logically equivalent statements.)

However, the *converse*

> If the ground is wet, then it is raining.

is certainly *not* believable. It may have rained hours ago. Or someone spilled some water.

Concrete examples may help you deal with the logical structure in the mathematical theorems.